# Audio devices not being autodetected

Tags: 18.04, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

Recently after my system updated packages, I restarted my computer and found that sound no longer works. `aplay -l` and pulseaudio both report that there are no sound devices, even though they were working fine previously.

I checked and found that the proper kernel modules were not loaded. Running `sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel` got my motherboard's sound device to immediately show up in pulseaudio, and `sudo modprobe snd_usb_audio` got my USB audio devices working as well.

I haven't edited any audio configuration files recently, but I'd like to get this working automatically so that Ubuntu will load the proper kernel modules at boot time after detecting my hardware.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 with Linux 4.15.0-39-generic

Comment: Can you try to boot with the older kernel, to see if this is a regression for the 4.15.0-39-generic that you're running now?

Comment: Just tried with 4.15.0-38-generic and had the same issue.

Comment: Can you recall when did this happen? Or if you can see any snd_hda_intel related error messages on boot (in dmesg)? I would suggest you wait for the kernel update in maybe 2 days to see if it helps. You can open a bug report on launchpad later.

Comment: One can study the output of `lspci -c | less` about `Audio` entries. E.g. `snd_hda_intel` string shows up there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reloading alsa?

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

In my case, alsa did know about the sound card, but the installed PulseAudio server ignored it completely. After running the command above, I had sound again.